# (secondary) human/primate advantages over other animals?

Tags: evolution, human-evolution, adaptation

I am trying to understand the advantages that humans have over other species, besides what you could call 'sentience-critical'.

What I mean by this is, the first set of answers you'll get is "more capable brains (in general), opposable thumbs, tools, comunication". But all that is core to sentience and civilization, not primates. I am more interested in the second set of answers, such as 'better temperature management'.

I suppose the question is, what advantages do primates have over other animals? Or, what traits are likely to be missing, compared to humans, from a hypothetical non-primate sentient creature?

Comment: Primates in general, or humans in particular?  I think the temperature management (which isn't necessarily better, just different to allow extended exercise in hot climates) is unique to humans among primates.  Otherwise the only things I can think of are trichromatic vision, and a forelimb structure that allows throwing.

Comment: Both work, and I'm actually interested in humand in particular, but since the line between what we can do as species and as sentiences is not too clear, I figured comparing our cultureless relatives to other animals could help. But those two examples are wonderful!

Comment: Pure speculation on my part but walking upright seems important as it frees up our hands for not only using tools or carry things, but it helps us stay clean because we can reach more of our body to remove unwanted pests.

Comment: @Cell that is interesting! I guess walking upright IS a primate trait! By my criteria, it'd be a trait I shouldn't demand from a civilised species... Well, that's surprising!